# How sort the below filename in order using shell script?

Tags: shell-script, shell

How sort the below filename in order using shell script?

```
abcd_exp_4_20180706.txt
abcd_exp_3_20180706.txt
abcd_exp_1_20180706.txt
abcd_exp_2_20180706.txt
abcd_exp_5_20180706.txt
abcd_exp_1_20180707.txt
abcd_exp_5_20180707.txt
abcd_exp_4_20180707.txt
abcd_exp_3_20180707.txt
abcd_exp_2_20180707.txt
```

expected output

```
abcd_exp_1_20180706.txt
abcd_exp_2_20180706.txt
abcd_exp_3_20180706.txt
abcd_exp_4_20180706.txt
abcd_exp_5_20180706.txt
abcd_exp_1_20180707.txt
abcd_exp_2_20180707.txt
abcd_exp_3_20180707.txt
abcd_exp_4_20180707.txt
abcd_exp_5_20180707.txt
```

Comment: Are the filenames stored in a text file? What are you wanting to do with them apart from sorting them? What is the bigger issue that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Kusalananda, No the filenames are not in text file. The files  come from one of our upstream to my local directory. I want to copy this files like the mentioned  sequence order to another directory one by one.

Comment: Why is it important that you copy them in a particular order and one by one? I'm trying to understand so that I don't solve a non-existing problem.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, parsing the output of `ls` is a [bad idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128987/18887). However, if you know all filenames follow this same format, then it's a reasonable approach.

```
$ ls | sort -t_ -k4 -k3,3
```

#### Explanation

- `ls |`: pipe the output of ls to…
- `sort -t_ -k4 -k3`: sort using `_` as a delimiter, first by the 4th column (e.g. `20180706.txt`), then by the 3rd column (e.g. `1`).

Comment: @Sparhawk, Thanks it works. But if the file name prefixed with some additional string means how to handle this

Comment: You shouldn't be using `ls` to do anything programmatically.

Comment: adding to above comment usually my filename is abcd_exp_1_20180706.txt but sometime it have prefixed with some string like xxx_abcd_exp_1_20180706.txt and xxx_2017_abcd_exp_1_20180706.txt, I want permanent solution for this. Please help me on this

Comment: @slm Agreed, as per my first sentence. I've added a link to clarify to the reader.

Comment: @perror Yes, I just put it in to be explicit, attempting to make it simpler to understand (but perhaps had the opposite effect).

Comment: @LSundar You could rename, removing the first `_`, sort, then rename, adding the `_` back. But you really need to add all this information in the original question, including the answers to Kusalananda's question. Please be specific in the pontential filenames.